# Blazor 8 Azure AD Authentication Issues

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I am having an issue with upgrading an application from Blazor 7 WASM to Blazor 8. I am trying to correct how the authentication with the application works now that Blazor is focused more on Blazor server rather than WASM. Here is my current setup:

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The UseAuth..() methods are before any additional middleware items as the documentation states.

AppSettings for the 'Settings' block:

```
"Settings": {
    "Authority": "",
    "Audience": "",
    "Tenant": "",
    "TenantId": "",
    "InstanceUrl": "",
    "Domain": "",
    "ClientId": "",
    "ClientSecret": "",
    "LoginScopes": [  ],
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "",
    "SwaggerRedirect": ""
  }
```

When the application launches, the browser directs immediately to the azure b2c login page, but it gets stuck in a loop. I expect that this is due to the authorize attribute being on my pages, but I'm not sure how this is supposed to work in this case. Here is the Routes.razor component:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not Found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(EmptyLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

I need the application to launch and redirect to the login page in my blazor app as it did in the WASM version of the app. I tried a suggestion I found on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoEiyVg5Npw) which involved adding a CookieAuthenticationEvents override, but this didn't work either.

Does anybody have any suggestions?